# A tool or framework to practice linear or logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, regression

I am looking for a tool framework that lets me implement linear and logistic regression. I would also like to add regularization and tune the parameters using gradient descent.

Is there any framework or tool that lets me do these?

I would like to basically practice these two machine learning models.

Comment: I believe RapidMiner handles both types of regressions.

Comment: What do you consider to be "practise"? And what do you expect from such a framework? I believe this question does not have an answer.
What is preventing you from implementing regression in Java, C, Python, R, Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to learn, you should try implementing them yourself in your favourite language! They're not very difficult to implement, and you'll learn heaps by doing it :), they're obviously not going to be as fast as a good C or Python implementation, so don't use them for any production code.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my suggestion. You can register for Andrew Ng's online course at https://class.coursera.org/ml.

The first two assignments are exactly what you want to practice, which are linear regression, logistic regression and regularization techniques.

-- sorry, I just notice that the registration for the current ml course is closed. The next one might open at the end of 2012 or early 2013. :(